# OLOO Difference in creation?

Tags: javascript

Are there any other differences between these two versions of Foo other than the second Foo has no proto chain?

typeof says there are both objects and other than that, I see no other changes in behavior etc., unless I'm missing something...

```
var Foo = {
    init: function(who) {
        this.me = who;
    },
    identify: function() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
    }
};

var Bar = Object.create( Foo );

Bar.speak = function() {
    alert( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
};

var b1 = Object.create( Bar );
b1.init( "b1" );
var b2 = Object.create( Bar );
b2.init( "b2" );

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

And

```
var Foo = Object.create( null );
    Foo.init = function init(who) {
        this.me = who;
    };
    Foo.identify = function identify() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
};

var Bar = Object.create( Foo );

Bar.speak = function() {
    console.log( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
};

var b1 = Object.create( Bar );
b1.init( "b1" );
var b2 = Object.create( Bar );
b2.init( "b2" );

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

Comment: If you are aware that `Foo` having no prototype implies that type coercion doesn't work (because there are no `valueOf` and `toString` / `[@@toPrimitive]` properties), then no, there is no other difference

Comment: @FelixKling Good point, until you mentioned it I did not really think of that. I can't think of an examples of why I would want that type of behavior on Foo though, is there some case where that would come in handy? I was trying to avoid it from going up the proto chain when it did not need to go any further than Foo